# Get child element

Tags: angular, typescript

Please have a look at below code.

```
import { Component,ViewChild,QueryList,ViewChildren } from '@angular/core'

@Component ({
selector : 'other-component',
template : `
          <h2>OtherComponent<h2>
          <table #tab id="tab">
            <tr *ngFor="let val of valArray">
              <td>{{val}}</td>
              <input type="checkbox" [value]="val">
            </tr>
          </table>
         <button (click)="getChecked()">click me</button>`
})
export class OtherComponent{
  valArray = ['one','two','three','four'];
  @ViewChild ('tab') elem;
  getChecked = () => {

    console.log (this.elem.nativeElement.children[0].children)
  }

}
```

At the end of the table row there is checkbox which has been assigned row value (JSON object) now I want to collect all the checked boxes in angular 2.

In plain javascript I can do this easily like below

```
var yy = document.getElementById('tab').getElementsByTagName('input');
```

I got what I was looking for by  `this.elem.nativeElement.children[0].children`

this gave me array of **tr** elements from which I got checked input boxes

Is there any better way to do this in angular 2?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change html (add `#cbx` to `input`) like:

```
<tr *ngFor="let val of valArray"><input #cbx type="checkbox" [value]="val"></tr>
```

Then in your component class:

```
@ViewChildren('cbx') checkboxes;
getChecked = () => {
  console.log(this.checkboxes.toArray().map(x => x.nativeElement));
}
```

It will print array of desired checkboxes

See also live **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/WLqeaRt5iKjyD6dVzaBc?p=preview)**

**Update**

Alternative way is using dom api directly:

```
@ViewChild ('tab') elem;
getChecked = () => {
  console.log(this.elem.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('input'));
  console.log(this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('input'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the intention of my question is how to reach to elements which are nested deep in html page,  rather than giving local reference i would like to get them by their tag name

Comment: Perhaps `@ContentChildren('tab', {descendants: true})` otherwise use `querySelectorXxx`

Comment: Instead of printing the values of the checkboxes, how can I uncheck them on a button press? The way I can think of is by calling a method which would do something like this:
this.checkboxes.toArray().map(x => x.checked = false);
But this is somehow not working.